# How to remove stage from URLs for AWS Lambda functions + Serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

I'm using Serverless Framework to deploy functions in AWS Lambda, but I can't find where/how I can remove the stage specifier from the URL endpoints created. The documentation does not seem to cover this part.

For example, this is my `serverless.yml` (with irrelevant parts omitted):

```
service: cd-mock
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: eu-west-1
package:
  include:
    - handler.py
functions:
  index:
    handler: handler.index
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
```

After a `serverless deploy`, the following service information is returned:

```
service: cd-mock
stage: dev
region: eu-west-1
stack: cd-mock-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  GET - https://ab1cd2ef3g.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/
functions:
  index: cd-mock-dev-index
```

Notice the `/dev` part in the URL endpoint, and also in the function. That `dev` is the default value for the `stage` parameter in the configuration file.

Specifying `stage: something` in the `serverless.yml` file will have that `/something` as suffix in the URL, and as part of the function.

**Question: how can I remove the stage specification from the generated URL endpoints, or: how can I prevent that stage specification to become part of the generated URLs?**

(That the stage is part of the function, is fine. That will be easy to separate `staging` and `production` functions in the AWS Lambda dashboard.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an API Gateway feature/convention NOT from Serverless Framework so `serverless` can't do anything about it.

API Gateway requires you with a stage and it is appended at the end of your endpoint.

API Gateway endpoints are meant for developers though so it is not meant to be user-friendly.

If you want it to be user-friendly, you can add a custom domain for it. Different stages can have different custom subdomains.

Answer (score 50):

One thing you can do is use a custom domain that you own (e.g. `mycompany.com`) and map that to your API Gateway. This way, rather than making a request to `https://ab1cd2ef3g.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/`, you would make a request to `https://api.mycompany.com/`.

There's a plugin called [`serverless-domain-manager`](https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager) that makes it much easier to set up this custom domains. Check out [this blog post](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-api-gateway-domain/) for a full walkthrough on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks - great answer. I wish I could accept both your and @dashmug's  answer. Because he was a bit earlier, and also provided some more explanation (mentioning that it was an API Gateway convention), I accepted his answer. Thanks for the link to `serverless-domain-manager` though!

Comment: No problem! @dashmug had a great answer. Glad you got what you're looking for.

Answer (score 37):

In the local environment, we may use the flag --noPrependStageInUrl when running the dev server: `sls offline start --noPrependStageInUrl` when using serverless offline. Online, we may set up a CloudFront or custom domain.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Very annoying that this is not the accepted answer and other solutions have a higher up-vote. Thanks a bunch for this! Great stuff!

Comment: Because this is not the answer to the question. The question is about `serverless deploy` command, not for `serverless offline`

Answer (score 14):

This can be solved by using `httpApi`, which does not prepend the stage to the URL path, instead of `http` which does.

Instead of

```yaml
functions:
  index:
    handler: handler.index
    events:
      - http: # <-- change this
          path: /
          method: get
```

use this

```yaml
functions:
  index:
    handler: handler.index
    events:
      - httpApi: # <-- to this
          path: /
          method: get
```

The `http` key creates an API Gateway "REST" (aka v1) endpoint whereas `httpApi` creates an "HTTP" (aka v2) endpoint. v1 has more features but v2 is faster and cheaper.

From the [Serverless docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api):

> Despite their confusing name, both versions allow deploying any HTTP API (like REST, GraphQL, etc.).

Full comparison
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html

Comment: For my case, I have to further add **payload: '1.0'** to the function configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Triggered by @dashnug's answer "API Gateway requires you with a stage and it is appended at the end of your endpoint" and another reply that I read elsewhere, I 'solved' the problem by making the stage specification a bit less telling (about which stage environment was referred to) by using `v1` as a stage. That also suggests some sort of API versioning, which is acceptable in my case as well.

So, my `serverless.yml` section now contains:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  memorySize: 512
  region: ${opt:region, 'eu-west-1'}
  profile: ${opt:profile, 'default'}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'v1'}  # A trick to don't end up with "production" or "staging" as stage.
```